# Radial chart on marker hover not working correctly

Tags: angular, charts, highcharts, radial

I have added to below js fiddle code

`https://jsfiddle.net/4xk57m6z/5/`

But on hover of marker its not showing correctly the data , only one marker gets highlighted on whichever marker i hover on

Kindly tell me the solution if u know

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAO4p.png)

On whichever marker point  mouse is hover but it highlights only one  marker.

I am using **angular-highchart** library

this is extra i have added under series:

```
            name: 'rest of marker',
            type:'scatter',//scattter
            marker: {
                 symbol:'circle',
            },
           data: [90,20,38,40,80]
        }
```

Comment: Hi, it's a bug I will report it and try to find workaround.

Comment: Here is issue that you can follow: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/17001